# Change SVG animation speed dynamically without position jumping

Tags: animation, svg, path

I have a simple SVG in which there is an element rotating around a circular path. When the user hovers, the rotation gets faster by changing the *dur* attribute. The problem is that the element jumps to a different position when it happens. How can this be solved?

```js
$('g').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('animateMotion').attr('dur', '3s');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find('animateMotion').attr('dur', '7s');
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width='500' height='500'>
  <g>
    <path id='circle' d='M 250, 250 m -200, 0 a 200,200 0 1,0  400,0 a 200,200 0 1,0 -400,0' fill='none' stroke='red' stroke-width='10' />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" transform='translate(-50, -50)'>
      <animateMotion dur="7s" repeatCount="indefinite">
        <mpath xlink:href="#circle" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adjust the animation timeline so that the animation is at the same point.

```js
var firstTime = true;
$('g').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('animateMotion').attr('dur', '3s');
    if (firstTime) {
      firstTime = false;
      return;
    }
    document.getElementById("root").setCurrentTime(
      document.getElementById("root").getCurrentTime() * 3 / 7);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find('animateMotion').attr('dur', '7s');
    document.getElementById("root").setCurrentTime(
      document.getElementById("root").getCurrentTime() * 7 / 3);      }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="root" width='500' height='500'>
  <g>
    <path id='circle' d='M 250, 250 m -200, 0 a 200,200 0 1,0  400,0 a 200,200 0 1,0 -400,0' fill='none' stroke='red' stroke-width='10' />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" transform='translate(-50, -50)'>
      <animateMotion dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite">
        <mpath xlink:href="#circle" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This works much better, but I'm still getting a jump the first time I hover. After that, it does work perfectly, but before there is still a jump.

Comment: Because the animation starts fast. It doesn't go slow till you've hovered once and stopped hovering. This seems odd to me but it's your functionality I suppose.

Comment: I apologize, I made a mistake in the initial post and the animation should start slow indeed. Do you know how to make it work having the animation with a slow initial value?

Comment: I do know but you really should try to figure that out for yourself. It's pretty obvious.

Comment: You are right, perhaps I'm having a slow day, but I didn't see it right away.